# Unable to call a Javascript class from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, function, web

Please have a look at the below  code

**TTSScript.js**

```
   function TTS()
{
    var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("yohan");
    var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();

    this.speakText = function()
        {
             window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
        }
    }
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <script src="/scripts/TTSScript.js"></script>
        <script>
           function speak()
           {
               var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello World');
               window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
           }

           function speak2()
           {
               var TTS = new TTS();
               TTS.speakText();
           }


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><button onclick="speak2()">Click me</button></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunatly when I click on the button in the html page, what I get is an error. It is below.

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (13:42:13:817 | error, javascript)
    at speak2 (public_html/index.html:23:26)
    at onclick (public_html/index.html:31:126)
```

I am not much familiar with JavaScript, can you please let me know why I am getting this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Is that the only error? is `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` defined in your browser?

Comment: a js fiddle would be welcome, in other case it's a "why isn't this code working?" question

Comment: @TimSeguine: as you can see, I can call `speak()` function with no issues, Yes, the `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` is defined.

Comment: @JustCause Actually I can't see that. You didn't say it until now, and you aren't calling it anywhere in your example.

Comment: JSFIDDLE version of your post: http://jsfiddle.net/bpprwfxa/2/

Comment: @TimSeguine: I don't think JSFiddle can solve this, as the speech thing is native to chrome.But thank you for making it, much appreciated :)

Comment: @JustCause that shouldn't really matter. The JSFiddle shows at least in an easily verifiable way for people who have chrome that the error does indeed happen exactly as your post describes.

Comment: @JustCause try this: instead of `var TTS` use something else, like `var t`.

Comment: @Gil: Then it says `Uncaught ReferenceError: TTS is not defined`

Comment: @JustCause He meant this, I think: http://jsfiddle.net/bpprwfxa/3/ no more type error. It seems chrome doesn't want you to shadow native code extensions to `window`. Since chrome defines `window.TTS`, It doesn't want you to overwrite it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved your problem.. :

1. don't use all capital names as variables

   var tts = new TTS();
   tts.speakText();
2. correct speak call is in the fiddle

   http://jsfiddle.net/bpprwfxa/4/

```js
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Yohan');
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
```

Comment: Not working in machine, working in fiddle. As I have mentioned, I the TTS function is belong to a different script, not an internal JS.

Answer (score 2):

After declaring a function, its name becomes a (locally) preserved word. It means that creating a variable with the same name might cause some problems.

I took your code and changed

```
var TTS = new TTS();
TTS.speakText();
```

Into

```
var tts = new TTS();
tts.speakText();
```

And the error disappeared.

Comment: Not working and having errors are two different things. Does this solve the error message? If it does you can now debug the function and find out what's stopping it from working.